# jQuery Tweets Method

Tags: jquery, tweets

I have been trying this http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/26733/ which seems to work fine, but 
when I copy paste my code in my rails 3.2 it doesn't show anything! What is going wrong? I need to get the tweets from a user, so I need an easy way to do it! Also why does the "tweets" method does not exist in the jQuery API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the fiddle, there is an ***external script*** included so it is working there.

> http://github.com/kerberoS/jQuery-Tweets/raw/master/js/jquery.tweets.0.1.js

If you want this to work on your code, you have to **include** the above script in your document too.

---

jQuery is a light weight JavaScript library, not a social networking toolkit, so it does not have any method as "tweets" in core library. However you can find plugins build for these specific reason, just like the one used in the fiddle you posted.

:)